How many ways can you create a 6-character password using only the numbers "1", "2" and "3", so that the numbers "1" and "3" never stand side by side?
So, question include repetitions and in any position I can put $3$ digits,
and it will be
$3^6$.
But there is I have the combinations with digits $1$ and $3$ together. How I can exclude this combinations ?
I tried like: I put $1$ and $3$ together and after I have $4$ positions for any 3 digits and this will be $3^4$. But there is "13 _ _ _ _" and this means 13 only in first positions. When I change positions of 13 this will be $5\cdot3^4$, but I think that I have a lot of mistakes here. Because "13 _ _ _ " and " _ 13 _ _" have a lot of same combinations, how I can count the repeat combinations ?  Or maybe I need another way to solve this question ??

Inclusion Exclusion should work, but you can also do it recursively.  Just keep track of the last character of your good string...you need that to know what character(s) you can put next.

https://oeis.org/A078057

We call a string "good" if it doesn't contain a $1$ and a $3$ side by side.
Let $u_n$ be the number of good $n$-character strings that end in $2$, and $v_n$ be the number of good $n$-character strings that end in $1$ or $3$. Then we have $u_1=1, v_1=2$; and for $n \ge 1$, $u_{n+1}=u_n+v_n$ and $v_{n+1}=2u_n+v_n$.
Using these equations, you can write down the values of the first six elements, and the answer is $u_6+v_6$. (I have done this $-$ it took about two minutes $-$ but I won't spoil your fun by telling you the answer.)

I solve by your formula and I have answer is 239. This answer looks like correct, but how I can be sure? And I am disappointed how you find $u_n$  and  $v_n$, can you explain or send some resource

I got $239$ too, so it's probably right.

Work recursively.  Let $a_n$ be the number of good strings of length $n$ than end in $1$, $b_n$ counts those that end in $2$, $c_n$ those that end in $3$.  Let $T_n=a_n+b_n+c_n$ be the total number of good strings of length $n$.
Then:  $$a_n=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}\quad \quad b_n=T_{n-1}\quad \quad c_n=c_{n-1}+b_{n-1}$$
Adding these we get $$T_n=2T_{n-1}+b_{n-1}=2T_{n-1}+T_{n-2}$$
Of course $T_1=3$ and $T_2=7$.  Easy to compute from here and we get $T_6=239$.
We could also solve the recursion in closed form.  That yields $$T_n=\frac 12\times (1+\sqrt 2)^{n+1}\,\,+\,\,\frac 12\times (1-\sqrt 2)^{n+1}$$
Note:  since $|1-\sqrt 2|<1$ the second term goes to $0$ for large $n$, so for large $n$ we get $$T_n\sim\frac 12\times (1+\sqrt 2)^{n+1}$$  For $n=6$ this yields the approximation $T_6\sim 239.001046$ which is already excellent.
Sanity check:  We get $T_3=17$ from the fomula but it is easily checked by hand.  The bad strings are $\{131,132,133,311,312,313,113,213,231,331\}$.  Making the count $3^3-10=17$.

+1 +Proposed edit regarding the closed form: further pool up factors to obtain
$$T_n=\frac 12\big(1+\sqrt 2\big)^{n+1}:+:\frac 12\big(1-\sqrt 2\big)^{n+1}$$

@Hanno  Good idea, thanks.  Will edit.
